# Notification bar unreadable while using Stackoverflow Android app

Tags: support, bug, android-app

Due to light tint of color, notification bar contents are unreadable.

[image: App screenshot!]

Comment: No repro on Nexus 5, Android 7.1.2 (LineageOS), SO app v1.0.4... it has a dark tint instead. Could you mention the device model, Android version and SO app version? (The SE app will fill this info automatically, but unfortunately SO app still doesn't have "report bug")

Comment: Also not reproducible on Nexus 5X, stock Android 7.1.2. Notification bar icons switch color scheme from light icons to dark icons as soon as the app opens, making the notification bar readable. You might want to file this bug with your ROM manufacturer if you're not using stock Android, as this might be a feature your ROM manufacturer forgot to implement.

Comment: im using Lenovo Vibe x2. Android 5.0. Every other apps works fine..

Comment: Are you using a peculiar theme perhaps?

Comment: The rom is already customized by lenovo.. It's OK if it's happening to a particular device!! :) . I thought it's something they didn't noticed while building the app..